# VBSCRIPT - SWbemObjectSet error 8004100C

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a script to detect when I have a second monitor connected, and to switch Rainmeter layouts accordingly. However, occasionally when I put my computer to sleep, then wake it up, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Shortcuts\Create\scripting\commandSniffer\detectMonitor.vbs

Line:   12

Char:   2

Error:  Not supported 

Code:   8004100C

Source:     SWbemObjectSet

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

All I really want to do is keep my script from crashing when I sleep my computer. If there's not an easy fix for this, how can I catch the error in the script and ignore it? Full source code below:

```
strComputer = "Localhost"
singleMon = "myLayout"
doubleMon = "myLayout(2monitor)"
rainmeterPath = """C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe"" !LoadLayout "
previousState = 1
set wshshell = createobject("wscript.shell")

do
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\wmi") 
    Set colItems = objWMI.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM WMIMonitorID")
    'Wscript.Echo strComputer & " has " & colItems.count & " monitors configured."
    if not isnull(colItems) and previousState <> colItems.count then
        if colItems.count = 2 then
            wshshell.run rainmeterPath & doubleMon,0
        else
            wshshell.run rainmeterPath & singleMon,0
        end if
        previousState = colItems.count
    else
        wscript.sleep 9000
    end if
    wscript.sleep 1000
loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
On Error Resume Next
```

transfers error handling from vbscript to you. You now need to test for errors after every call that might cause one.

```
If err.number <> 0 then
    'fix error or ignore
    err.clear
    'If decide to crash
    'err.raise(err.number, blah, blah, blah)
    'wscript.Quit
End If
```

Error handling is a chain. From lowest function call up to the app. Windows looks for error handlers, if it can't find one it crashes. Err.raise allows you to propagate errors up the chain.